# Sql тип значения

Tags: sql, oracle

Как определить тип значения в селекте
Например,

```
select coalesce(t1.col_name, t2.col_name) from table_name t1 left join table_name2 t2 on... where rownum=1
```

Пример не самый удачный, но для понимания, что мне нужно

Да, можно посмотреть структуру таблицы и понять тип, но есть ли функция для того, чтобы оракл сам вывел, какой тип будет храниться в переменной? Или такого нет в оракле?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087161/oracle-identify-data-type

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться функцией DUMP, которая позволит узнать тип поля. Туториал - https://oracleplsql.ru/dump-function.html